Can you pattern match on Python type annotations?
Can you pattern match on Python types?
I've seen simple examples:
import builtins

match x:
    case builtins.str:
        print("matched str")
    case buildins.int:
        print("matched int")

But I'd like to pattern match on a nested type, something like Annotated[Optional[Literal["a", "b", "c"]], "something here"] - is this possible?

Do you want to match if x was annotated with that annotation, or do you want to match if x is literally an annotation object with that structure?

To put it differently, if you were using if instead of match, would you write if x == Annotated[Optional[Literal["a", "b", "c"]], "something here"], or would you write something else?

I want to match if x is literally an annotation object with that structure and ideally destructure it

Pattern matching is fundamentally compiled down to a chained series of isinstance and == calls, among others. This means that, if you can express Annotated[Optional[Literal["a", "b", "c"]], "something here"] as a series of isinstance, ==, etc. calls, you can do pattern matching.
The problem with trying to do pattern matching on items from typing is that the types of the objects typing.Annotated[...], typing.Optional[...], etc. are implementation details (they're subclasses of typing._GenericAlias, and their instance variables and properties are not public), whereas pattern matching (specfically class patterns) is a style which ideally works with programming against a public API. If you don't care that you're accessing implementation details, then this could work:
import types
from typing import *

x = Annotated[Optional[Literal["a", "b", "c"]], "something here"]

AnnotatedAlias = type(Annotated[Any, Any])
UnionAlias = type(Union[Any, None])
LiteralAlias = type(Literal[None])

match x:
    case AnnotatedAlias(
        __args__=(
            UnionAlias(__args__=(LiteralAlias(__args__=("a", "b", "c")), types.NoneType)),
        )
    ):
        print("x matched")


I think NoneType is going to get treated as a capture pattern, not a value pattern - it'll match anything and assign it to NoneType.

@user2357112 good catch, thanks!
